# Cross Browser: How Can I Adjust the Vertical Position of an Element, Based on Viewport Height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alignment

I've got a dock of icons that I would like vertically centered. This of course would vary, based on screen resolution, etc. What I've currently done, is got the height of a parent DIV, which is sized at 100% of the viewport:

```
    var pageHeight = $('#sidebar').height();
```

Then, I get the height of the icon container, as this is not predetermined in CSS:

```
    var socialDockHeight = (document.getElementById('social_dock_container').offsetHeight * numberOfIcons);
```

Note: this only retrieves the height of one icon, for some reason, perhaps because they are coded in an array? I then calculate the new position, and assign it to the element, via jQuery:

```
    var y = (pageHeight / 2) - (socialDockHeight / 2);
    $("#social_dock_container").css({ 
            top: y + "px"
    }).show();
```

This works great in Chrome, but not IE, FF, or Safari.

Comment: can't you just put the social dock container to the bottom with `bottom: 0;`? sorry if I misunderstood you

Comment: And how exactly does it not work?

Comment: I'm attempting to centre the container, as opposed to having it aligned to the bottom.

Comment: Andy, the icons, and container do not display at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not going to use `$(window).height()`, then use `$('#sidebar').outerHeight();`, so you get all the other good stuff like paddings and margins on the element.

Also don't forget about when a user resizes their window.  Use `.resize();` for that.

Comment: Resize is something I'll include, however, for now I am worried about having the icons display. As for the sidebar parameters, I hadn't included any margins, etc.

Comment: What value is being returned for `socialDockHeight` ? Have you checked?

Comment: Ah, here is the problem, Safari and Chrome return the value I am looking for. IE and FF return outrageously large values. Any idea as to why this is? It is now obvious the container is pushed way off the page

Comment: I wouldn't know without looking at the HTML + CSS, what i would say from here, is try to get the height or position of another object or maybe even the window.

Comment: Anyway, all I intend to do now is remove the variable assignment for the container height, as I can retrieve it with an alert. I've hard coded in half of it's height, and all is well. Thanks a ton Zee Tee!

Comment: I'm guessing the difference between the browser's returned heights would have to do with the array? Chrome and Safari seem to return only the height of a single element in it, while IE and FF return the array's entire height. Or at least, that is my current assumption.

Comment: try using `.outerHeight` instead of only `.height()`

Answer (score 0):

You want to have your icons always beeing positioned in the middle of the screen? If your Icons are not that big, why not do:

```
#social_dock_container
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

**EDIT**

As Zee Tee mentioned, of course you need to set margin-top as followed:

```
$("#social_dock_container").css('margin-top', '-' + socialDockHeight / 2 + 'px' );
```

Comment: absolute huh? you may need some `margin-top:-` with that

Comment: The icons are quite large, this pushes the container off of the page, as I have my overflow set to hidden, in this element.

Comment: 50% will take it down half the page, but won't center it vertically. You would need to use `margin-top:-Npx` N = half of the object's height.